# Cuda работает, но GPU не производит вычислений. Pytorch-Cuda (Jupyter)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cuda, anaconda, pytorch

[image: Библиотеки]

У меня установлена Cuda 11.8 в соответствии с версиями библиотек. torch.cuda.is_available() дает True и соответственно всего распознает одно устройство GPU, но при запуске нейронной сети CNN в диспетчере задач GPU не нагружается. Код проверен через Collab (т.е. с точки зрения кода все в порядке, вычисляется на GPU). В настройках CUDA используется видеокарта NVIDIA GTX 1070 Ti, драйверы обновлены, ОС - Windows 10. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
    def get_default_device():
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return torch.device('cuda')
    else:
        return torch.device('cpu')
device =get_default_device()   

def to_device(data, device):
    if isinstance(data, (list,tuple)):
        return [to_device(x, device) for x in data]
    return data.to(device, non_blocking=True)

class DeviceDataLoader():
    def __init__(self, dl, device):
        self.dl = dl
        self.device = device
        
    def __iter__(self):
        for b in self.dl: 
            yield to_device(b, self.device)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dl)
```

Ну и соответственно

```
train_dl = DeviceDataLoader(train_dl, device)
val_dl = DeviceDataLoader(val_dl, device)
to_device(model, device)
```

device(type='cuda')

[image: Информация по ПК]

Хочу также добавить, что, по идее, вычисления у меня могут производится, так как

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__); print(torch.randn(1).cuda())
```

дает результат tensor([1.4457], device = 'cuda:0')
Обучение:

```
@torch.no_grad()
def evaluate(model, val_loader):
    model.eval()
    outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
    return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)

def fit(epochs, lr, model, train_loader, val_loader, opt_func=torch.optim.SGD):
    history = []
    optimizer = opt_func(model.parameters(), lr)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Training Phase 
        model.train()
        train_losses = []
        for images, labels in train_loader:
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            loss = model.training_step(images, labels)
            train_losses.append(loss)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Validation phase
        result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
        result['train_loss'] = torch.stack(train_losses).mean().item()
        model.epoch_end(epoch, result)
        history.append(result)
    return history
```

Comment: Судя по времени, вроде бы, вычисления производит CPU, в диспетчере задач нагрузка 25%, если использовать CPU напрямую, то 45%. Я впервые установил CUDA на ПК и не понимаю, что может повлиять на это.

Comment: вы бы пример привели своего кода и примеры посмотрели. сеть должна загружаться в гпу device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

Comment: @nexoma , добавил

Comment: @nexoma как говорил ранее, проверял в Collabe - обучается с GPU, поэтому, мне кажется, ошибка не в коде, а в ПО.

Comment: ну, на pytorch жаловаться такое себе, проблема значит в коде. но код я ожидал другой.

Comment: вот тут присмотритесь https://www.learnpytorch.io/pytorch_2_intro/   я может не понимаю ничего, но даталодеру cuda не нужна.

Comment: @nexoma, насколько я знаю, необходимо, чтобы данные, используемые в вычислениях, хранились в области GPU, если мы работаем с CUDA. По крайней мере все время мне приходилось переносить их примерно таким образом или напрямую: 
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

Comment: Без cuda для даталодера вылезает ошибка RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same or input should be a MKLDNN tensor and weight is a dense tensor

Comment: да, data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device) - это правильно

а вот тут надо искать ошибку RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor)

не тот тип и надо с этим разбираться

Comment: с виндой тяжко работать с нейронками, лучше перебраться на линукс, там инфраструктура получше, т.к. изначально пишется на линуксах.

Comment: @nexoma, добавил фрагмент кода - функции обучения. Добавил batch.to(device), но, по смыслу это аналогично классу DeviceDataLoader(). Работает без ошибок, а GPU все также не напрягается.

Comment: ну так он напрягается при больших потоках данных, возможно у вас нагрузка на гпу мала.

Comment: в моём малом опыте нвидиа "напрягалась" на трех видеопотоках 1000х800 точек 25 кадров в секунду

Comment: @nexoma Т.е. использование в 0% и то, что GPU-память не заполняется - это может быть нормально?

Comment: ну сами прикиньте, хотя могу и ошибаться. в гпу расположена сеть, в неё подгружаются данные. и это за один раз. вот попробуйте запустить свой скрипт одновременно в 5 экземплярах и проверьте нагрузку командой nvidia_smi

Comment: @nexoma проредактировав код, чтобы переводить на cuda методом to(device), теперь хотя бы выделяется ядро с операцией copy, раньше его вообще не было. Возможно, я и правда представлял себе это все неправильно и вычисления не большие. Разница с Collab в 9 раз (6 минут против 56 на одну эпоху), возможно моя видеокарта сильно хуже Tesla и этим все объясняется, но в таком случае я не вижу разницы между обучением на процессоре и на моей видеокарте, так как скорость почти одинаковая, вот и решил, что вычисления проходят мимо GPU

Comment: несомненно правильный вывод, но, загрузите 4к видео, большую сетку и... ваш цпу загнётся. прорыв цпу ожидается на цпу с сотнями ядер, но гпу тоже не будет стоять на месте, вопрос в обоих случаях в оперативке и загрузке-выгрузке данных с гпу.


успехов!

Comment: если вопрос стоит о производительности, обратите внимнаие на amd roc, они сделали нормально, с pytorch работает.

Answer (score 0):

ок. начинаем с простых шагов

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models

model = models.resnet18().cuda()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
compiled_model = torch.compile(model)

x = torch.randn(16, 3, 224, 224).cuda()
optimizer.zero_grad()
out = compiled_model(x)
out.sum().backward()
optimizer.step()
```

работает на cuda?

Comment: RuntimeError: Windows not yet supported for torch.compile на проверке: def check_if_dynamo_supported():
if sys.platform == "win32", хотя у меня 64-разрядная система >_>

Comment: Добавил информацию о всем, что может быть связано с работой cuda, а также добавил проверку, по которой вычисления идут на gpu